# How do I override the bool operator in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I'm defining a `ReturnValue` class in C++ that needs to report whether a method was successful. I want objects of the class to evaluate to `true` on success and `false` on error. Which operator do I override to control the truthiness of my class?

Comment: Before you do this, please be aware of the pitfalls of implementing `operator bool`: see http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/32145/1954

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The simple answer is providing `operator bool() const`, but you might want to look into the [*safe bool idiom*](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html), where instead of converting to bool (which might in turn be implicitly converted to other integral types) you convert to a different type (pointer to a member function of a private type) that will not accept those conversions.

Comment: And if you use the very latest compilers, you can use the new C++0x feature `explicit operator bool()` to avoid the implicit conversions.

Comment: Very nice! I'll probably go with the easy `operator bool() const` in my current use case, just for simplicity's sake, but the safe bool idiom seems much more suitable for real production code. It is kind of sad that C++ forces you into craziness like this, though. :-/

Comment: @Bo, as luck would have it, since this is a personal project, I get to choose my compiler, and GCC 4.5 supports this. Thanks!

Comment: @Bo, if you make this an answer, I'll accept it, as it is certainly the nicest way to handle truthiness for a class. Oh, and greetings from Stockholm! :)

Answer (score 14):

Well, you could overload `operator bool()`:

```
class ReturnValue
{
    operator bool() const
    {
        return true; // Or false!
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use ***explicit*** keyword or it will interfere with other overloads like ***operator***+

Here is an example :

```
class test_string
{
public:
   std::string        p_str;

   explicit operator bool()                  
   { 
     return (p_str.size() ? true : false); 
   }
};
```

and the use :

```
test_string s;

printf("%s\n", (s) ? s.p_str.c_str() : "EMPTY");
```

Comment: Consider `explicit operator bool() const noexcept`.

Answer (score 3):

overload this operator:

```
operator bool();
```