# C++ class operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It's possible to overload the not operator for a class:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
       bool Test;
       const bool operator!(){return !Test;}
};
```

So that...

```
TestA A; A.Test = false;
if(!TestA){ //etc }
```

...can work. However, how does the following work?

```
if(TestA) //Does this have to be overloaded too, or is it the not operator inverted?
```

I will add, having read it, I am slightly confused by the typedef solution that is employed, and I don't fully understand what is occurring, as it seems somewhat obsfucated. Could someone break it down into an understandable format for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override the bool operator in a C++ class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829487/how-do-i-override-the-bool-operator-in-a-c-class)

Comment: Look around for the "safe bool idiom".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an `operator bool()`. This takes care of coercion to bool, making statements as your above one possible.

Comment: Note that the resulting `bool` is convertible to `int`, which may or may not be what you want. Generally, an `operator void *` is safer.

Comment: If I overload the int operator for the class, would it overload the boolean-to-int conversion? I have an idea for the int operator anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think the compiler would try that after failing to find an `operator bool()`

Comment: @arne: Oh, sorry (although what you said was useful), I mean, if I had both a bool and an int operator defined, and I tried to assign to an int, would it call the int or bool first? I'd assume int, but I know C++ sometimes can act strangely.

Comment: It would use the `operator int()` first, because that would save one implicit type coercion.

Answer (score 2):

You overload `operator void*` (like the standard library's iostreams) or use boost's trick of using an "unspecified_bool_type" `typedef` (safe bool). It does NOT automatically invert your `operator!`